# Will this for loop call set.size() at every iteration of itself (set is a vector)?

Tags: c++, optimization

A [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25984757/what-is-the-most-efficent-for-loop-bounds-checking) similar to this one has been asked before, it has no conclusive accepted answer.

Will this for loop call *set.size()* at every iteration of itself (*set* is a vector)?

```
for(int i = 0; i < set.size(); i++)
```

Would the code bellow be any faster?

```
int size = set.size();  
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
```

Is the VS 2010 compiler smart enough to not let the program call *.size()* at every iteration?

Comment: By that do you mean, did I try to accurately measure the code with a timer or did I try viewing the program with a dis-assembler? No, I don't know how to do either of those things.

Comment: "Is the compiler smart enough to not let the program call .size() at every iteration?" -- Suppose you were adding items to `set` within the loop ... would you want the compiler to optimize away the call?

Comment: This is a question about specific compilers. If you had a specific compiler in mind then you could ask about that

Comment: This is with the VS 2010 compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general modern optimizing compiler can do pretty powerful optimizations. It is very rarely worth it to do such optimizations yourself, usually you will just be getting in the compilers way. Before you even look at optimizing code you should profile your code to determine were the performance issue are.

A quick test with [godbolt (*see live code*)](http://goo.gl/WGZwrE) using this code:

```
void function() {
  std::set<int> set ;
  set.insert( 10 ) ;
  set.insert( 20 ) ;

   for(int i = 0; i < set.size(); i++) 
   {
     printf( "%d\n", i ) ;
   }
}
```

Shows that it is directly accessing the count variable and not making a function call,  the relevant assembly is:

```
movq    $0, 56(%rsp)    #, MEM[(struct _Rb_tree_impl *)&set]._M_node_count
```

and:

```
cmpq    %rbx, 56(%rsp)  # ivtmp.115, MEM[(long unsigned int *)&set + 40B]
```

So it would seem at least in this simple case the `gcc` optimizer was able to do the quick trick you wanted to do yourself. Although the generated code is different `clang` seems to be doing something similar as well.

**Update**

The question was updated to mention Visual Studio.

I don't know of an online tool to generate the Visual Studio assembly otherwise I would check that as well but I would not be surprised if Visual Studio also performs a similar optimization. As we can see the optimization is definitely possible. Once you generate the [assembly in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020498/how-to-view-the-assembly-behind-the-code-using-visual-c) it is matter of determining whether a call to `size()` is made every iteration of the loop or not.

Answer (score 3):

A compiler might be smart enough to cache the result of `set.size()` if it could deduce that the result would not change throughout the lifetime of the loop. That's not a trivial optimization. If speed were critical I would not rely on the compiler making it. It would be safer, and clearer, to make the optimization explicit, so one looking at the code needn't wonder if there is a missed optimization opportunity.

And on the opposite side, if speed were not a concern (which it usually isn't), I would not bother with the microöptimization. Even if speed were a concern, you should still profile your code first and make sure this line of code actually is a bottleneck before applying any optimizations. That's a good rule of thumb in general.